# How to handle errors and success at the same time on a Google Apps Script Webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am wondering how the client-server communication with Google Apps Script Webapps works. In the html page I call my functions with

`google.script.run.doSomething();`

and I can add a

`withFailureHandler(onFailure);`

OR

`withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)` but I can't add both..

So when I want to call a server-side function  I normally want to handle the response in the UI ?differently if it is a success than a failure, right? But I want to handle both right? So why do I have to choose between one of them?

Also another problem is that I could not find any information about the actual errors you can have on the server side so that your `withFailureHandler(onFailure);` can handle them. Can I just do a `throw new Error("everything is broken - tell that the user")`? If there are permission errors, are they handled? How do I generate an error on the server side so that I can handle it on the client side properly?

Comment: You can add both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html) does not specify it clearly, but **you can** implement both a success and error handler simultaneously

Sample:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).getUnreadEmails();
     function onSuccess(numUnread) {
       var div = document.getElementById('output');
       div.innerHTML = 'You have ' + numUnread  + ' unread messages in your Gmail inbox.';
     }
     function onFailure(error) {
       var div = document.getElementById('output');
       div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
     }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE

To simulate a failure based on the documentaiton sample, change the working `code.gs` part

from

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getUnreadEmails() {
  return GmailApp.gotInboxUnreadCount();
}
```

to

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getUnreadEmails() {
  return GMailApp.gotInboxUnreadCount();
}
```

After deploying the WebApp, the html will output:

[image]

Comment: hm I swear I tried that and it did not work. But it does. But how can I throw an error so that the onFailure gets triggered?

Comment: withFailure is triggered when the .gs script encounters an error, easy to do ;)

Comment: I just updated my answer with a sample to make it clearer!

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#script_runners),

> You can use any combination and any order of withSuccessHandler(), withFailureHandler(), and withUserObject(). You can also call any of the modifying functions on a script runner that already has a value set. The new value simply overrides the previous value.

### Sample:

```
const gsr = google.script.run;
const runnerF = gsr.withFailureHandler(onFailure);
const runnerS1 = runnerF.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess1);
const runnerS2 = runnerF.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2);

/*Both runners have the same failure handlers, but different success handlers*/
runnerS1.callServer();//failure => onFailure;success => onSuccess;
runnerS2.callServer2();//failure => onFailure;success => onSuccess2;
```